# Where did (the language in) this proof of Godel's incompleteness appear?

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, computability, proof-theory

Many years ago I ran into the following proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem 
*(here $T$ is an ["appropriate"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02023013) theory of arithmetic.)*:

> First, we observe that Tarski's undefinability theorem can be slightly tweaked to say that for all $M\models T$, the theory of $M$ can't be the standard part of an $M$-(parameter-freely-)definable set. Next, by the usual representability arguments we have that every computable set is **invariantly definable**: if $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is computable and $M\models T$ then $X$ is the standard part of a definable set in $M$. Now if $S$ were a computable satisfiable completion of $T$ we would get a contradiction by looking at $M\models S$. If we want, we can then replace "satisfiable" with "consistent" via the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).

My question is:

- **Where did this argument appear?**

I'm **not** interested in the question of whether this is a "genuinely different" argument; rather, I'm just interested in its **presentation** in terms of invariant definability. This was a notion first introduced by Kreisel following Godel/Herbrand and subsequently studied by others *(see e.g. [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780720422337500253), [2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2270854), [3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02762011))*. My vivid recollection is that the argument above appeared as a footnote in the first paper mentioned above, but it turns out it's not there after all.

*(A related question is when the variant of Tarski's theorem mentioned above first appeared explicitly. Of course the proof really is a trivial variation of the usual argument, but I'm still interested in when it was observed.)*

Comment: FWIW my personal take is that it *is* meaningfully different from the other arguments I'm familiar with, but for a very silly reason - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72062/what-are-some-proofs-of-godels-theorem-which-are-essentially-different-from-t/353900#353900). That said, it does also have a minor convenience advantage when we generalize it to higher logics appropriately (e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350303/robinson-arithmetic-for-some-levels-of-l/350378#350378) by using its generalization I avoid needing to talk about the proof theory of infinitary logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the lack of reference provided here and [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355650/where-did-this-presentation-of-godels-theorem-appear), as well as my own lack of success in finding a reference, I'm going to tentatively say that this particular approach has not appeared *as such* in print. I'll delete this answer of course if someone supplies a reference in which it appears, but I think at present it's appropriate to move this off the unanswered queue *(I've made my answer CW since the line between answer and non-answer here is a bit blurry, so this doesn't feel quite right as a reputation-producing answer)*.